# variable changing to true before setInterval is finished

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6

`showMoves` is a function made to show flashing for a simon game.

When the flashing lights are over I clear the interval to stop it and then I set `game.playerTurn` to `true` so I can click on colors, but `game.playerTurn` is changing to `true` as soon as `showMoves` is activated.

I want `game.playerTurn` to stay `false` until the `showMoves` function is finished showing flashing.

Here are the functions I'm using `game.playerTurn` in -

```
game.playerTurn = false;

//for flashing lights
function showMoves() {
    let i = 0;

    const start = setInterval(function () {
        if (i >= game.computerMoves.length) {
            clearInterval(start);
            game.playerTurn = true;
            return;
        }

        const move = game.computerMoves[i];
        setLight(move, true);
        setTimeout(setLight.bind(null, move, false), 1000); //Using bind to preset arguments

        i++;
    }, 2000);
}

function setLight(color, isOn) {
    if (isOn) {
        sounds[color.id].play();
    }
    color.style.backgroundColor = isOn ? colors[0].get(color) : colors[1].get(color);
}


//compareMoves is fired everytime I click on a color
function compareMoves(e) {
    if (e === game.computerMoves[game.counter]) {
        game.counter++;
        //This is if all the moves were chosen correctly
        if (game.playerMoves.length === game.computerMoves.length && e === game.computerMoves[game.computerMoves.length - 1]) {
            simonHTML.displayScore.textContent = ++game.score;
            game.playerTurn = false;
            resetMoves();
            randomMoves(++game.turn);
            showMoves();
            game.counter = 0;
        }
    } else if (game.strict) {

        //if your move was wrong do this
    } else {
        game.playerMoves = [];
        game.counter = 0;
        game.playerTurn = false;
        showMoves();
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate any help with this. Here is a link to the game and all the code https://codepen.io/icewizard/pen/JLBpNQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you setting game.playerTurn back to false?

```
function showMoves() {
  game.playerTurn = false;
  let i = 0;

  const start = setInterval(function() {
  if (i >= game.computerMoves.length) {
      clearInterval(start);
      game.playerTurn = true;
      return;
  }

  const move = game.computerMoves[i];
  setLight(move, true);
  setTimeout(setLight.bind(null, move, false), 1000); //Using bind to preset arguments

  i++;
}, 2000);
}
```

Seems to work for me in the codepen example you provided

Comment: sorry I made a typo, its fixed now and its under compareMoves function. The first time is when the player chooses all the colors correctly, and the second time is when the player gets a color wrong.

Comment: I placed game.playerTurn = false at the beginning of the showMoves function and it seems to work as you asked to me

Comment: This is working for me too, thanks. I'm not sure why though since in my actual code game.playerTurn is already set to false in an object I made and I keep setting it to false before I start showMoves again in the compareMoves function